# Angular Firestore Cart duplicates total

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am writing a cart component for a club application where they can sell merchandise.

When I retrieve the cart items and add the totals together, on the first load (even if there is only one item) the cart total doubles. Then when I go back to the merchandise (or any ) component and back to the cart, the value is correctly displayed.

```
cartTotals(cartTotal = 0.0) {

    return this.afs.collection(`cart`)
      .doc((this.uid))
      .collection(`items`)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .forEach((element => {
        element.map(e => {
          const id = e.payload.doc.id;
          const val = e.payload.doc.data()['price'];
          const qty = e.payload.doc.data()['qty'];
           this.total = val * qty / 100;

          return {id, cartTotal};
          
        })
        cartTotal += this.total;
        this.cartValue = cartTotal;
      }));
  }
```

I cant see why it duplicates the total on first load.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, i think I have figured it out. Nothing wrong with the code it seems.

When an item was added to the cart, I was sending the user straight to the cart.

I removed that action and now, when the user clicks on the cart icon in the tool bar, the totals are correct in the cart and I can now generate the Stripe Checkout Session.